# How to send raw socket packets using Winsock Kernel (WSK) in kernel-mode driver?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, driver

I am developing a **kernel-mode driver** for Win7 and later. I want to send **custom IP packets** in the driver (I want to specify all fields for IP layer). I found the **Winsock Kernel (WSK)** technique but it only said how to send and receive TCP and UDP packets. I know that in user-mode, there is **raw socket** in WinSock API. So I wonder **if there is also a raw socket interface for Winsock Kernel**? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WskSocket` support `TCP`, `UDP` and "raw sockets" for custom IP paquets : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> SocketType [in]
>
> ```
> The type of socket that is being created. The following socket types are supported:
>
> SOCK_STREAM
>
>     Supports reliable connection-oriented byte stream communication.
> SOCK_DGRAM
>
>     Supports unreliable connectionless datagram communication.
> SOCK_RAW
>
>     Supports raw access to the transport protocol.
> ```

Comment: It seems to be right, but I didn't find the function to send raw packets? TCP packets can be sent using `SendData` and UDP packets use `SendDatagram`. It's best if an example can be provided.